# One part of layout in many activities in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is concept of my idea. I have my activity:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.actionbartest.ClassTabs
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is ClassTabs class:

```
public class ClassTabs extends LinearLayout{

    Button nextButton;
    LinearLayout tabs;
    private int count = 0;

    public ClassTabs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public ClassTabs(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabview, this);
        setupViewItems();
    }

    private void setupViewItems() {
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);
        tabs = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toptab);

    }
    public void addTab(Button child){
        if(child!=null){
            tabs.addView(child);
            count++;
        }
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

and tabView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toptab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@color/blue">
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to do something like that: you are in first activity. Only what you see is blue 40dp layout and button "next". You click on the button and you see second activity and you see the same layout with blue layout and button, but in the blue layout is one button on left side. When you click again button "next" and you will see third activity with the same layout but in blue layout is two buttons, one next to one, etc. How can I do that I have the same layout in every activity, but second activity should know that button was added in the first activity, and the third activity should know and show two buttons etc?

Answer (score 0):

Put all button to your layout, but set their visibility gone, 
then

activity 1 : set button1 visibility to visible

activity 2 : set button2 visibility to visible

activity 2 : set button2 and button 1 visibility to visible

[EDIT1]

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

by catching size you can use if condition to decide which button will be displayed

Comment: and use `include` in your Activity layout XML to avoid duplication

Comment: I can't use that solution, because I need add buttons depending on screen size. When I add buttons on tablet I can put a lot of buttons, but when on phone I can add only 4-5 buttons to fit layout. And only what I need in second activity is this blue layout, because in future every activity will be different. Only what should stay is this blue layout with button/buttons

Comment: To do this you can use different layouts, layout-small, layout-normal,layout-large,layout-xlarge. Or you can get screen size look at edite answer pls